# Random numbers shared between canvases

Tags: java, canvas, random

I am new to Java, and I am also new to posting a question online. So please bear with me.

I am currently constructing a Java program which displays several canvases, and I require the different canvases to use shared and/or inherited information. Let's assume for simplicity that canvas C1 displays a polygon with random vertices on a circle. Currently these vertices are created in a coordinate class and are then instantiated by a drawing class. I am now trying to store these values in a way which allows the second canvas C2 (via drawing class) to use them, but without instantiating it, as I need the same sequence of random numbers.

Let this be a simplified example of my coordinate class:

```
public class Coord {
    public Complex[] z = new Complex[5];

    public Coord() {}

    // create n random vertices (length of a and z will match)
    public Complex[] randCoord(Complex[] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            z[i] = new Complex(200 * Math.random(), 200 * Math.random());
            }
        return z;
    }

//    public static Complex[] getCoord() {
//        return z;
//        }

}
```

The commented out section is one of my million attempts to generate a static version of the coordinate list, but I am not allowed to return z as it is not a static variable (in this case). I am probably missing something painfully obvious in regard to transferring between static and non-static methods, but any insight on how to store the random sequence (and likewise, how to call it) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern would be helpful :

```
public class Coord {

    private static final Complex[] z = fixedRandomPoints(5);

    private Coord() {}

    //this is the method you call from both canvases
    public static Complex[] getInstance() {
       return z;
    }

    private static Complex[] fixedRandomPoints(int n) {         
        final Complex[] results = new Complex[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){         
            results[i] = new Complex(200 * Math.random(), 200 * Math.random());            
        }         
        return results;
    }

}
```

The only thing thats unclear is the relationship of this class to the 'a' variable, which I think you need to explain a little better.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked perfect! You are right about the 'a' variable - in this example it is probably pointless, but that's due to my simplification. Can I add one more (probably more involved) question? I have a button which repaints both canvases, and this button is supposed to generate a new random sequence (for use in both canvases). How can I call this from the ActionListener which repaints each canvas?

Comment: You should be able to simply say Coord.getInstance() - does that not work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But to illustrate the question in detail I would have to share a lot of code, though I probably should not post a new question just for that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read up on the MVC-pattern: Model-View-Controller.

Secondly, it looks like what you're currently trying to do can simply be done by declaring z to be static:

```
public static Complex[] z = new Complex[5];
```

Comment: Oh right, adding static got rid of the specific error returned -- and I file that under "painfully obvious". Thanks for the link!

Comment: Upon further reading, this MVC architecture surely seems promising. It may create more problems than it solves considering my beginner status, but I think I'll give re-structuring a shot.